# Mathematica DSolve gives zero solution for 1D heat PDE

Tags: differential-equations

This could possibly be duplicate. I do not know. Hard to search. But I just found out that for a very simple heat PDE in 1D with homogeneous boundary conditions, `DSolve` gives answer which does not make sense to me. It gives zero as the solution.

Here are the specs

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}  & =k\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}\\
t  & >0\\
0  & <x<L
\end{align*}

Initial conditions

$$
u\left(  x,0\right)  =\sin\left(  \pi\frac{x}{L}\right)
$$

BC

\begin{align*}
u\left(  0,t\right)    & =0\\
u\left(  L,t\right)    & =0
\end{align*}

Here is the Mathematica code to solve it using `DSolve`

```
ClearAll[x,t,L0,k]
eq=D[u[x,t],{x,2}]*k==D[u[x,t],t];
bc={u[0,t]==0,u[L0,t]==0};
ic=u[x,0]==Sin[Pi x/L0 ];

(*now tried with assumptions and no assumptions, same result*)

(*sol=DSolve[{eq,ic,bc},u[x,t],{x,t}]*)
sol=DSolve[{eq, ic, bc}, u[x, t],{x, t},Assumptions->{L0 > 0,t >= 0,x >= 0}]
```

Here is Mathematica answer

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is no inconsistency in boundary and initial conditions.

But this can be easily solved by hand. The analytical solution is

$$
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sin\left(  \frac{\pi}{L}x\right)  e^{-k\left(
\frac{\pi}{L}\right)  ^{2}t}%
$$

`NDSolve` solves this correctly. Here is side-by-side of the solution by `NDSolve` and the above analytical solution to verify that the above analytical solution is correct.

```
values={k->2/3,L0->2}; 
numericalSol=NDSolve[Evaluate[{eq,ic,bc}/.values],u,{x,0,2},{t,0,3}];
myAnalyticalSolution[x_,t_]:= (Sin[ Pi/L0 x] Exp[-k ( Pi/L0)^2 t])/.values;

Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Plot[u[x, t] /. numericalSol, {x, 0, 2}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-.1, 1}}, PlotLabel -> "NDSolve", 
     ImageSize -> 250], 
    Plot[myAnalyticalSolution[x, t], {x, 0, 2}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-.1, 1}}, PlotLabel -> "analytical", 
     ImageSize -> 250]}}],
 {t, 0, 3, .01}]
```

[image]

**Question is** Why did `DSolve` gives zero as solution? And is there a way to correct this at user level (may be using some option or such).

Is this a bug in DSolve?

Using Version 11.1.1 on windows 7.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If you set `L0=1` then it works perfectly. Weird.

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with the eigenvalues.

Comment: @yohbs Not so weird : `DSolve` is not "aware" that L0>0

Comment: @andre FYI, Tried assumptions that length>0 but has no effect. Actually DSolve does not seem to use assumptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to work around the issue is to tell Mathematica that `L0` is [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ). For instance:

```
NumericQ[L0] = True;
```

Then:

```
eq = k D[u[x,t], {x,2}] == D[u[x, t], t];
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[L0, t] == 0};
ic = u[x,0] == Sin[Pi x/L0];

sol = DSolve[{eq, ic, bc}, u[x,t], {x,t}]
sol //TeXForm
```

> {{u[x, t] -> E^(-((k [Pi]^2 t)/L0^2)) Sin[([Pi] x)/L0]}}
>
> $\left\{\left\{u(x,t)\to e^{-\frac{\pi ^2 k t}{\text{L0}^2}} \sin \left(\frac{\pi 
>    x}{\text{L0}}\right)\right\}\right\}$